# Ansibleのロールのディレクトリ構成の考え方について

Tags: ansible

Ansibleでロールを作成する場合は、下記のようなディレクトリ構成にするようですが、
目的は **どこに何が書いてあるかを分かり易くする（可読性を高める）** ことだけでしょうか？

```
roles/
  ロール名/
    defaults/
    files/
    handlers/
    meta/
    tasks/
    templates/
    tests/
    vars/
```

単一のファイルとしてではなく上記のように分割するからには、
何か理由があると思っているのですが、いかがでしょうか？
（例えば、より再利用性が高くなるような参照の仕方があるとか）
手元の本ではそれが確認できずもやもやしております。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

それぞれが役割を持ったディレクトリとなっています
・defaultsでロールの初期変数を司る
・filesでcopyモジュールなどのsrcファイルを相対で指定した場合に最優先される検索先になる
・handlersで実行したい処理をまとめたてタスクの最後に一度だけ実行
・metaでGalaxyに登録して他の人が分かりやすい情報を記載
・tasksでmain.ymlからinclude_varsでvars配下の変数ファイル読み込んだり、include_tasksでtasks内のタスクファイルを読み込んで実行する
・templatesにtemplateモジュール実行時のsrcファイルを相対で指定した場合に最優先される検索先になる
・testsにインベントリファイルやロールを呼び出すタスクファイルを配置し、ロールをゲットした人がとりあえず実行できるようにしておく
・varsはinclude_varsでファイルを相対で指定した場合に最優先される検索先になる

とくにdefaultsとvars、filesとtemplatesは混同しがちかなと思いますが役割が違います
・defautls　デフォルトの変数、host変数やExtra変数で上書き可能
・vars　include_varsで読み込む変数、host変数やgroup変数では上書きできない、Extra変数で上書き可能

・files　配置したいファイルそのものを置く、バイナリなど
・templates　設定ファイルなど、実行時に固有の値を埋め込みたいものを置く、テキストファイルが原則